# Can't test my Google Home Action in Actions Console Simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

We've been having trouble keeping Wonder available on Google Assistant and Home. We keep resubmitting and then find out there's some bug that gets us taken down.

One thing that has made it hard is that we cannot test Wonder in the simulator in the Actions Console. Here is what a session looks like: [Wonder test session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlYl0.png)

When I expand the last message I see the following error: [Cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIFje.png)

Is there any way you could help us get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Assistant available in the simulator has a subset of the features of the assistant available in your phone or Google Home device. If you want to use the entire set of voice interactions, please use the assistant on your physical devices. If you want to test your smart home action, you can use [Test Suite](https://developers.home.google.com/tools/test-suite).

Also note that Google Home projects do not support dialogflow anymore. I see you have the dialogflow-es-fulfillment tag in your project. If your project is set up as a dialogflow project, you might need to set up a new Smart Home project on the [actions on google console](https://console.actions.google.com/).